# Matching a tuple with certain elements of a sequence of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, sequence, string-matching

I have a sequence of answer tuples (for a word search game) that contains this:

```
[(0, 0, 'downright', 'plain'), (5, 4, 'up', 'on'), (5, 1, 'left', 'mainly'), (4, 5, 'left', 'falls'), (0, 2, 'right', 'spain'), (0, 3, 'downright', 'in'), (1, 3, 'upright', 'rain'), (3, 0, 'left', 'the')]
```

I want to match a guess tuple to an answer, a guess is a tuple containing:

```
(0, 0, 'downright')
```

How would I match the guess tuple to one of the answer tuples in the sequence?

*My attempt (however it sometimes gives False even though it does match):*

```
def is_valid_answer(answers, guess):
found = True

for x,y in enumerate(answers):
    if guess == (answers[x][0:3]):
        return found
    else:
        found = False
        
        return found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop ends already if the first item of `answers` doesn't match to `guess`, because you return `found` (`False`) immediately. Therefore your loop always does only one iteration and compares only the first item.

Return only in the loop (with `True`), if you found a match. If there's no match you can return `False` after the loop.

```
def is_valid_answer(answers, guess):
    for x in answers:
        if guess == x[0:3]:
            return True
    return False
```

Btw: You don't need `enumerate` here, you can simply compare the yielded value (`x`).